# Access VBA to Return Total of Column in a Query in a MsgBox

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am learning Access and VBA.  I'm using Access 2007.

I'd like to create something in VBA that runs a query and then returns a value in a message box, that value being the Total Sum of one of the columns.

The column that is summed is called Documents.  The Query lists all the groups of documents still active, but what's most important is the sum.  I want to create VBA for a button on the main form that runs each different query and then tells me the sum it gets when it runs each one.

How do I do this?  I don't know how to use the number that Access calculates as the sum total as an object in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregating or summarizing data from a query or table in VBA often makes use of the domain aggregate functions: DSum (as here), DLookup, DCount, and so forth.

```
MsgBox "Total documents: " & DSum("Documents", "[Query Name Here]", "[Criteria] = ""Optional""")
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel silly for not knowing that but I'm on my way to getting this.  One question: how do I make it so that the criteria is inputted by the user via input box?  I have some code I can post but it keeps giving me a syntax error

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  Excellent it's working exactly as I needed it to.  Thanks so much!!